# How can I make a page which is no larger than the size of one equation?

Tags: equations

I would like to output only one equation, not on a whole page, but document to fit size of the equation.

Just like the image output from the codecogs website.

How can I do this with LaTeX?

Comment: You can use an `empty` and via the `standalone` document class create an equation-only "page".

Answer (score 4):

For example, class [`standalone`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/standalone) can be used:

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\mbox{$\displaystyle E=mc^2$}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Remarks:

- TeX only sees character bounding boxes of the font, not the bounding boxes of the visual appearance of the glyphs, thus it is possible that the visual appearances exceed the font character boxes. There I have added `1pt` additional margin here by option `border=1pt`.
- I do not know, why `\[`...`\]` or environment `displaymath` is not working, therefore I have simulated it by `\mbox{$\displaystyle ...$}`.

### Alternative

You  can also generate the equation on a page on its own with page style `empty`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\[ E=mc^2 \]
\end{document}
```

After the `pdflatex` run the white margins can be cropped by [`pdfcrop`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pdfcrop), that
uses Ghostscript's `bbox` device to determine the visual bounding box.

Comment: ??? i don't see `border=1pt` in the example code. (in my experience, `standalone` results in a page that is *much* too tight.)  regarding `pdfcrop`, i can confirm that it does a very nice job.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thanks, I have forgotten to paste the updated test file.